# How can someone decide if heavy calculations should be made in the server or in the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

What should someone think about in order to choose whether to do some heavy calculations on the client or in the server.

What key points should be taken into consideration?

For example:

I want to implement a process to update the records of a table in a database from an Excel file, so what would be a better approach of doing this knowing that the Excel can have more than 20k rows.

### Option A

- Read the Excel on the client.
- Send the JSON data in the body with fetch to the endpoint.
- Update the database from endpoint.

### Option B

- Send file to the server endpoint.
- Read the Excel on the server.
- Update the database with the information retrieved.

Comment: if im not wrong the difference between both of your options is the type of file you are sending that is JSON or Excel. You Can Evaluate which of these methods to use based on the following: a) Size Of Data Sent  b) Complexity in Coding The Parser in Client or Server-Side.

Comment: I see, then both options are equally valid,   it just need to be tested and evaluated depending on different factors and decide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no right answer here, both options will have their own tradeoffs.

You need to figure-out which option will be better fit for your usecase and your architecture.

Option A if:

- You are running with very limited server resources
- You dont know how many clients you will have
- Your server charges you based on amount of processing - Like AWS Lambda.
- You want to validate the file/data on the client side itself. If the user uploads incorrect data, you can check it before starting the upload.

Option B if:

- You have good amount of server resources
- You are using fixed cost servers
- You are ok with validating the file on server side. If the user uploads incorrect data, you will have to ask them to reupload the entire thing

Also, with both options, you will have to do some sort of batch processing. You need to figure-out where you want this to be done.